# Which code files layout scheme use (language agnostic)

Tags: software-design

There are at least two possible code files layout schemes:

- so called Socks Drawer - where you put files to directories according to its type (*.html in Views; *.cs in Model; controllers in Controllers; services in Services directory, etc);
- by feature (or modular) - in which all entities (model, views, controllers, etc) for one feature are grouped together in a directory (and common stuff is extracted as a separate group); and structure for other features are in separate directories;

Everywhere I read the last one is better.

Reference examples:

- http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/4/21/code-organization-angularjs-javascript
- http://www.codergears.com/Blog/?p=768
- https://aelia.co/2012/10/03/how-to-neatly-structure-your-code/

That makes me ask a question: why socks drawer layout for code packaging is more popular than packaging by feature? Why it's forced by frameworks (ASP MVC; Ruby on Rails; etc);

Example of Socks Drawer layout (all controllers are in Controllers directory, all models in Models directory):

[image]

Example of by-feature-layout (controllers and entities are in separate groups for each app feature):

[image]

Comment: No accepted answer for now... For the time being, I have to assume that Software Engineering doesn't have a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

*TL;DR- The answer about how to organize your project is ultimately a question.  That is, what is the best way to represent the files in your project to fit your team's workflow and the constraints of the architecture?*

There are several things to consider when deciding how to lay out a project.

1. Does the underlying platform make distinctions between different types of files, or different functional areas? For example, Rails specifies a very specific layout that gives you a lot of behind-the-scenes magic for free.
2. Does your team's workflow suggest a particular arrangement?
3. What is the basic unit of work for the project? Does it make sense to divide the structure into modules, or is there some other layout that fits the project better? (Models/Views/Controllers, Presentation/Reporting/Business Logic/Database, HTML/Images/JavaScript/Dynamic Content)
4. What architecture best describes the project? Is this MVC? Is it n-tier? Is it based on some pattern like Factories, Producers/Consumers, etc? Make the layout match the architecture, and when you have to find that database tier code, you'll know right where to go.
5. Are you working in a compiled language that logically separates compiled code into units? (Think .net assemblies)
6. Is the code based on some existing framework, or a fork of some existing project? (In which case it makes sense to match the layout of the original.)
7. Does the business have rules/standards about how to lay out the project?

There are ultimately very few fixed rules to follow.  The layout that is best, provided that the language doesn't specify specific rules, is the layout that helps you find and understand the content of the code.  If the sock-drawer approach makes this happen for you (and/or your team) then that's the best layout to use.  If a modular approach is best for you, then use that.  There's also nothing to say that you can't use a "modular sock-drawer" approach, where the code is divided into modules, and each module is divided by functional area.

Comment: Sorry, but "Do whatever you like" is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the only feasible scheme to general purpose frameworks. In order to make a feature oriented organization, you need to know the system features, which is impossible to be known before you have a specific system to implement using such frameworks.

There is an interesting concept that is related to this preference:  [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).  Convention over configuration (also known as coding by convention) is a software design paradigm which seeks to decrease the number of decisions that developers need to make, gaining simplicity, and not necessarily losing flexibility. When the convention implemented by the tool matches the desired behavior, it behaves as expected without having to write configuration files. Only when the desired behavior deviates from the implemented convention is explicit configuration required.

Comment: Well, frameworks could just not force to use specific layout.

Comment: There is another interesting concept that is related to this preference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration I am not sure if it answers the question in a broad sense, but it can give you a hint on why framework designers choose one way over another.